# Is there a way to spring batch read the field set configuration from database?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

We are trying to develop a framework on top of spring batch, basically it has to read the data from database like fields, fields order, file location..etc..

Is there any existing frameworks to achieve this, otherwise please shed some light on this...

Thanks,
MK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any such extension available over the framework. You might have to write your own customizations to achieve a database driven configuration for Spring Batch.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want Spring Batch to read in?  Have you looked at ItemReaders?  http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html

In your ItemReader constructor you can read in whatever configuration you require.

And see:

[Reading Records From a Database in Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167717/reading-records-from-a-database-in-spring-batch)